# SQLAlchemy backref and backpopulates conflicts with relationship and mapper mapped has no property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In FastAPI application I am using sqlalchemy library. I have tried to establish a many to many relationship as described below:

```
PostCity = Table('PostCity',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('post_id', Integer, ForeignKey('post.id')),
    Column('city_id', Integer, ForeignKey('city.id')))

class DbPost(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'post'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
  image_url = Column(String)
  cities = relationship('DbCity', secondary=PostCity, backref='post')


class DbCity(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'city'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
  name = Column(String)
  posts = relationship('DbPost', secondary=PostCity, backref='city')
```

During add and commit commands it throws an error:

```
SAWarning: relationship 'DbCity.posts' will copy column city.id to column PostCity.city_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Dntention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add the parameter 'overlaps="cities,post"' to the 'DbCity.posts' relationship. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/qzyx)  city = DbCity(name=city_name)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68322485/conflicts-with-relationship-between-tables) suggests to use **back_populates=** , however, when I am replacing **backref** with **back_populates** in both DbPost and DbCity classes it gives another error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper 'mapped class DbCity->city' has no property 'post'
```

What is the reason of this and how could I fix it ?

Comment: `cities = relationship('DbCity', secondary=PostCity, back_populates='posts')` and `posts = relationship('DbPost', secondary=PostCity, back_populates='cities')`

Comment: you have to use back_populates instead of backref or pass column name into backref ,it looks like `backref=cities` or `back_populates=city`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning

> SAWarning: relationship 'DbCity.posts' will copy column post.id to column PostCity.post_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'DbCity.post' (copies post.id to PostCity.post_id), 'DbPost.cities' (copies post.id to PostCity.post_id).

is emitted because the two relationships are duplicating each other. The `backref` on each creates a relationship on the other.  You only need to configure the relationship on one of the models, the `backref` will automatically configure the other model.

Comment: Note, however, that the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html) say "The relationship.backref keyword should be considered legacy, and use of relationship.back_populates with explicit relationship() constructs should be preferred."